# Как вычислить сложность алгоритма в условном блоке?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Имеется такой метод:

```
template<class RandomIt>
static auto SelectionSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)
    -> typename std::remove_reference<decltype(first)>::type {
    // Declare a base type for RandomIt
    typedef std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*first)> BaseType;

    int length = std::distance(first, last);
    BaseType* res = new BaseType[length];
    auto limits = std::numeric_limits<BaseType>();
    auto lastMin = limits.min();

    for (int i = 0; i < length;) {
        int count = 0;
        auto min = limits.max();

        for (auto j = first; j != last; ++j) {
            auto v = (*j);

            if (v > lastMin) {

                if (v < min) {
                    min = v;
                    count = 1;
                } else if (v == min){
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }

        for (; count > 0; --count, ++i) {
            res[i] = min;
        }

        lastMin = min;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Пытаюсь понять, как оценить его сложность... Конкретно, не понимаю, как оценить сложность (стоимость, количество выполнений) в этом участке кода:

```
if (v > lastMin) {

    if (v < min) {
        min = v;
        count = 1;
    } else if (v == min){
        ++count;
    }
}
```

P.S. Мне не нужен ответ вида O(n^2). Я хочу понять, как я должен рассуждать в этом блоке, проставляя стоимость (просто c1, c2, ..., cm) и количество выполнений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [Амортизационный анализ](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7). Никто не оценивает условие в цикле отдельно от цикла. Оно просто будет `О(1)`. В данном случае это вы должны посчитать количество раз, когда оно вызовется. Для этого нужно рассмотреть циклы. Оба идут от first до last. Приняв `n=last-first`, получите `O(n^2)`. В данном случае это метод усреднения.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку и за пояснения! Вроде, понял.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что амортизационный анализ в данном случае - не совсем в тему. Здесь просто достаточно рассмотреть два цикла; амортизационный же анализ нужен, например, когда есть какие-то редкие, но дорогостоящие операции. Скажем, в векторе добавление элементов - когда время от времени требуется новое выделение памяти и операция копирования всего содержимого - которая O(n), но *из-за редкости выполнения в среднем*, при большом числе добавлений дает O(1).